# Why don't Textmate snippets autocomplete but work when using the "Bundle" menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, textmate, textmatebundles

**Edit:** 
Below is my original question. After solving my problem, I thought I'd re-edit this so others may benefit. The root question is "A certain subset of textmate snippets aren't working."

**Original Question:**
In Textmate, I can't use ruby on rails migration snippets like mtab⇥, mcol⇥, or t.⇥  in my db/migrate/ files. I've tried setting the file type as "Ruby on Rails" as well as "Ruby" and even "Sinatra" but have had no luck. These commands do work when I go through the bundle menu however. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get the feeling this has something to do with the scope of these bundle snippets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had ActiveRecord::Migration misspelled so the snippets that rely on matching that string were failing! Always check the snippets source! :)

Comment: @Greg, I shall. But I have to wait until tomorrow for the two day time wait on marking your own answer as the answer. Also thank you for editing the title!